# how can i make my custom libraies to be version controlled in angular and record its version in package.json like other libraries of node

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-directive, web-frontend

How can I implement version control for my custom Angular libraries, which contain generic code shared across my projects? These libraries encapsulate reusable functionality, and I want to manage their versions similar to other npm packages listed in my package.json. What steps should I take to achieve this version control for my Angular libraries?

Comment: Publish the Angular libraries on npm and add them as a dependecy to your projects?

Comment: I made those libraries for internal use, so publishing them on Angular will be of no use.

Comment: You can use a private npm registry. You can host your own (such as [Verdaccio](https://verdaccio.org/)) or use a cloud provider (such as npm).

Comment: Also, npm allows you to install packages from a Git repository. And it allows local links with [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-link). Perhaps you can use that.